# "Guess the number" in Java

Tags: java

We are meant to to create a program in java in which the computer randomly guesses a number between 1-100 and allows the user to guess to the number. If the number is lower than the random number the program should say: lower! and of higher, the program should say: higher! If the user guesses the right number it should say congratulations you guessed the right number in X amount of tries, This is what I have so far, when I execute in cmd it just spams either higher or lower and I need help working it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int random, guess, attempts;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        random = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
        attempts = 1; 

        System.out.print("I am thinking of a number between 0 and 100, what do you think it is?");

        guess = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        while (guess != random) {
            if (guess > random) {
                System.out.print("Lower!");
                attempts += 1; 
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Higher!");
                attempts +=1;
            } 
        }

        System.out.print(random + "is the correct answer and it took you" + attempts + "attempts to guess it!");

    }        
}
```

Comment: You might try asking for another guess after you tell the user if their previous one was too low or too high.  If you never change the value of `guess`, why would you expect the while loop to end?

Comment: put this line after if-else in while loop  => guess = keyboard.nextInt();

Comment: FYI if guess is not equal to random number then you are attempts += 1;  doing times,why not simple include it in while loop to decrease one line code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only take a single guess and stuck yourself in the while loop, it's like if the number randomized by the program is **70**, and for example if the user gave his first attempt as **50**, the code will enter the `while loop` as the number is not **70**, but it won't come out as you coded `while(guess != random)` and guess will ever equal random in our case, and it will be always **lower** for an infinite time because you give him the ability to enter a single attempt and then you enter an endless while loop without giving him the ability to change his attempt through it, So, you must allow him to has his second, third, ..etc attempts inside the while loop itself, like the following:

```
    guess = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    while (guess != random) {
        if (guess > random) {
            System.out.print("Lower!");
            attempts += 1; 
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Higher!");
            attempts +=1;
        }
     guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only reading the input once and then looping on it forever (you read the input outside the loop).

Try reading the input inside the loop and using `do-while` loop:

```
guess = 0;        

do {
    guess = keyboard.nextInt(); 

    if (guess > random) {
        System.out.print("Lower!");
        attempts += 1; 
    } else {
        System.out.print("Higher!");
        attempts +=1;
    }
 } while (guess != random);
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the `guess = keyboard.nextInt();` into the `while` loop to ask again and again.

Answer (score 0):

The random number generate the number once the we will call the method `isNumCorrect` again using while loop until it returns true and the guess count will increase every time the number pass through `isNumCorrect`

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class guessGame {
    int guessedNumber;
    int userNumber;
    int guess_count;
    public guessGame() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        guessedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
    }
    void userNum() {
        System.out.println("GUESS THE NUMBER");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        userNumber = sc.nextInt();
    }
    boolean isNumCorrect() {
        guess_count++;
        if (userNumber == guessedNumber) {
            System.out.printf("yes you guessed it right in %d guesses", guess_count);
            return true;
        } else if (userNumber < guessedNumber) {
            System.out.println("too low");
        } else {
            System.out.println("too high");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class cwh_42_guess_the_number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        guessGame g = new guessGame();
        boolean b = false;
        while (!b) {
            g.userNum();
            b = g.isNumCorrect();
        }
    }
}
```